# Rpy2 in python (AWS EC2): Syntax error: _cdata: FFI.CData

Tags: r, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, rpy2

I am trying to call rpy2.robjects which is giving below mentioned error. I am using rpy2 package(3.4.5) in python 3.5.10. R installed version is 3.4.1.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>

    import rpy2.robjects
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>

    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 13, in <module>

    import rpy2.rinterface_lib._rinterface_capi as _rinterface
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_rinterface_capi.py", line 97

    _cdata: FFI.CData
          ^
Syntax error : invalid syntax

[Rp2_error][1]
```

I am running this command from AWS EC2 instance where it is required to call an R function from python.

The same command is working in windows after setting R_HOME.

In EC2 instance, tried 2 paths for R_HOME,

```
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/usr/lib64/R/'
```

or `'/usr/bin/R'`
The issue persists in both cases.

R.home is `'/usr/lib64/R/'` (R prompt)

Answer (score 1):

rpy2 3.4.x requires Python >=3.6 as described in the documentation ([installation section](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/overview.html#installation)). The error you see is because Python 3.5 did not support typing.

You need to upgrade your Python version. Python 3.5 support ended 1 year ago and its not safe to use it - you may be exposed to unpatched security bugs. Given that support for 3.6 ends in two months I would recommend upgrading straight to 3.7 or 3.8.